# Parse multiple date column combinations with pandas read_csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am importing a csv file. There is a "date" column that has the day and then several (~20) other columns that have time of day. I have tried to use parse_dates= with read_cv but when I combine more than 1 pair of columns I get a "ValueError: Date column arrival already in dict" were arrival is the second column to be read in the parse_dates= dictionary.
Here is what I am doing (brief example):

```
df = read_csv('DH_timing_prep_stata_v4.csv', sep=',', index_col='pt_id', 
               parse_dates={'sch_appt_time_':['date', 'sch_appt_time'],
                            'arrival':['date', 'arrival']})
```

If I rename the columns when parsing its ok:

```
df = read_csv('DH_timing_prep_stata_v4.csv', sep=',', index_col='pt_id', 
               parse_dates={'d_sch_appt_time_':['date', 'sch_appt_time'],
                            'd_arrival':['date', 'arrival']})
```

I tried to just rename the columns after importing

```
df.columns = ['sch_appt_time_', 'arrival', 'other', 'columns...']
```

The problem with this approach is that if I make any change in the parse_dates dictionary the order of the columns changes and therefore the renaming is no longer valid.

My goal is to end up with the same column names as are in the cvs file. What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: What is your question exactly? When using a dict to specify the parsing, you can only use new column names not present in the data with the current implementation (and therefore you get that ValueError).

Comment: That makes me sad. I don't get the error for only one pair of columns.i.e. parse_dates={'d_sch_appt_time_':['date', 'sch_appt_time']}) If I want to end up with the same col names is there a way to change them after the fact without knowing the order of the col?

Comment: But the example with one pair of columns you give uses a different name for the new column, so it is logical you don't get an error then. For renaming, you can also use a dict in the `rename` method, so that way you don't have to rely on the column order (``df.rename(columns={'d_sch_appt_time_':'sch_appt_time_'}``). You can always file an enhancement request at https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues if you think this would be a nice feature.